# How to find mean for a categorical column in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to find the minimum, mean, median, maximum, standard deviation and variance for Mercury. I am unsure on how to find something for a column. I have been trying to use the code data(mean) but it is not working. I have attached a picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P00Vu.png)

Comment: In stead of posting an image of your data, you can copy the output of `dput(head(data))` and add that into your question. Then people can use and test the data you are using directly.

Comment: You need to reference a column `mean(data$Mercury)` I assume.

Comment: thank you that did work. How would you find something like standard deviation on R?

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data using `dput` as requested in the first comment. Also, if something "did not work," please explain what happened (did you get an error, or perhaps an unexpected result?). You are more likely to get useful answers if you can provide others with enough information to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `dplyr` package with `_if` syntax

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(mean, sd, var, min, max, median))
```

I think this would give what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dplyr::summarise() function for your columns in your data frame:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  School = c("A R Kaufman Public School", "Abraham Erb Public School", "Alpine Public School", "Avenue Road Public School", "Ayr Public School", "Baden Public School"),
  Mercury = c(50, 29, 38, 1, 61, 16),
  Lead = c(10, 8, 15, 16, 0, 3),
  PCB = c(532, 440, 518, 487, 517, 491),
  Arsenic = c(9, 6, 10, 2, 13, 4))

summarise(df, min = min(Mercury),
          max = max(Mercury),
          mean = mean(Mercury),
          median = median(Mercury),
          sd = sd(Mercury),
          var = var(Mercury))

#   min max mean median       sd   var
# 1   1  61 32.5   33.5 22.02499 485.1
```